# How to make Xcode 8 team id match Apple Developer team id?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8, apple-developer

I am definitely signed on to the same Apple ID in both cases. I've tried a lot of sign out and sign back in, and "download all profiles". But as you can see the team ID on the apple developer website doesn't match either of the two team id's on my Xcode profile.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnlNM.jpg

This discrepancy is preventing me from uploading my app to the app store because the website claims the bundle id is "not available". Well yeah, it is taken, by my alter-ego in Xcode 8.

Comment: Are you using automatic or manual profile management? Also what do you mean the bundle id is "taken by my alter-ego in Xcode 8"? If you've developed an app using Max Loh (Personal Team) you _cannot_ submit an app using that same bundle id using Max Loh. The bundle id is taken because _you_ took it.

Comment: Automatic. I think you must be right. All this confusion might be caused by the fact that I was using "Personal Team" and only registered for Apple Development Program after I finished developing the app. Then com.maxloh.BeerVision was unavailable for registration. Then when I realized com.beervisionapp.BeerVision WAS available, I must've screwed with Xcode in such a way that my PERSONAL account claimed it first? So then BOTH bundle id's became unavailable.

Comment: "All this confusion might be caused by the fact that I was using "Personal Team" and only registered for Apple Development Program after I finished developing the app" Right, so before you registered for the program by paying your $99, you allowed everything to happen automatically, including the fact that that bundle ID got registered thru your Member Center automatically. Then you made a second mistake when you used a different team when you signed up.

Comment: So that's the problem and there's nothing much you can do about it. You could attempt to _transfer_ the bundle ID from one team to the other, I suppose, but the simplest solution would be to use a different bundle ID.